# Login to Facebook Without Leaving App

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook SDK and I use the standart way of logging in a user (I use a FBSDKLoginButton). The problem is that when the user clicks on the view my app goes to the background and safari opens.

My app got rejected from the appstore because of this.

How can I make the login happen inside my app?

Comment: what was the rejection message?

Comment: "We noticed that the user is taken to Safari to sign in or register for an account, which provides a poor user experience"

Comment: have you tested with the device logged in and with the FB app installed?

Comment: The user doesn't need the Facebook app installed in order to login to facebook on my app.

Comment: Sure, but if it is installed it should be used

Comment: But that isn't the problem

Comment: it might be, if they expected to use the FB app or the device credentials and your app went to a web view that's a fail...

Comment: Because of changes on iOS 9, the login flow is now expected to go through the Safari Webview. There was some code in place in order to avoid this if the person had FB installed, however this has been disabled for now.